# Test for when a rospy publisher become available

Tags: ros, rospy, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I noticed that you must sleep for some amount of time before a rospy publisher actually starts to work.  I was wondering if there is any way to test for this?

```
pub = rospy.Publisher('foo', bar)
pub.publish(bar('a'))    # does not publish
rospy.sleep(1)
pub.publish(bar('b'))    # actually does publish
```

Will publisher.get_num_connections() do this?

```
pub = rospy.Publisher('foo', bar)
print pub.get_num_connections() # prints 0
rospy.sleep(1)
print pub.get_num_connections() # prints 1
```

In my case it goes from 0 to 1, but will this simply increment by 1 in the general case?  And if so, what if this node is started with several other nodes in a launch script?  Is this safe to do and will it give me the guarantee I am looking for?

```
pub = rospy.Publisher('foo', bar)
num = pub.get_num_connections()
while not rospy.is_shutdown() and pub.get_num_connections() == num:
    pass
pub.publish(bar())
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9665/test-for-when-a-rospy-publisher-become-available/) by [baxelrod](https://answers.ros.org/users/86/baxelrod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 794 on 2011-04-06

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [baxelrod](https://answers.ros.org/users/86/baxelrod/) on 2011-04-07**:
Interesting, I didn't know about that.  But I don't think it will suit my needs for this particular example.  Because I would have to spin a loop to publish messages, then also block on this test.  I can be done, but it would be really messy.

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2011-04-06**:
Would it be sufficient to know when messages have started appearing on the published topic?  If so, I have used             rospy.wait_for_message(topic, topic_type, timeout=None) to wait for a particular topic to become live before continuing in the script.  You can find its documentation at http://www.ros.org/doc/api/rospy/html/rospy.client-module.html#wait_for_message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is my standard response:

There are two ways of communicating in ROS: publish/subscribe and services.

ROS is a publish/subscribe system. Think of it like watching live TV.
If you tune in 5 minutes late, you miss the five minutes.  There may
be infinitely many subscribers, so a publisher can neither wait nor
guarantee that every subscriber hears the message.  In your program,
the subscriber doesn't hear the message because it tunes in *after*
your publisher publishes its first message.

In the ROS system, you are expect to either:

a) keep publishing a message at a certain rate

b) use 'latching', which, like a computer circuit, latches the value
on the publisher until it publishes a new message.

If you wish to *guarantee* a single message is delivered, you should
be using services.  With services, the service client knows there is
only a single service provider.  Thus, there is a contract that the
service request message will be delivered, or an error will be
provided.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-04-14**:
They have subscribed, but the connection to the publisher can not be initialized until the publisher has been initialized, and then the subscriber contacts it and requests data.  Only when all of that is complete can it connect.

**Comment by [baxelrod](https://answers.ros.org/users/86/baxelrod/) on 2011-04-14**:
Latching the publication seems to do the trick.  But I am slightly confused as to why.  I thought latching was for if you publish a message then someone subscribes sometime later, they will still get the message.  But in this case, someone is already subscribed, and I publish before my publisher is active.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-04-08**:
Based on the comments above it sounds like a latched publisher would take care of your needs.